# access phpmyadmin extern with mysql workbrench (10061)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Goodday guys,

I've a ubuntu WEMP server and I also installed phpmyadmin. I can access my phpmyadmin by typing the IP adress or domainname and then adding `/phpmyadmin` to it.

Now I want to connect it with MySQL workbrench. I already added a username in phpmyadmin with `martijn@%` and I updated the `config.php` file by phpmyadmin to:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '95.85.9.114';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['passwd'] = "PRIVATE:)"
```

[MYSQL WORKBRENCH ERROR 10061 ERROR PNG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkhM7.png)

Can someone help me with this? I'm a little bit of a newby in the server world. I always payed for a ready server with everything installed easy to configure. But now I've my own server

Comment: You've said you've configured a user `martijn@%` but in the config file you've used `root`.

Answer (score 1):

Make yourself clear what a client/server architecture means. MySQL is a server, phpMyAdmin and MySQL Workbench are both clients. How can two clients connect to each other in such a scenario? You cannot do that. You can only connect MySQL Workbench to your MySQL server (as you do with phpMyAdmin). Use the same credentials for connection unless MySQL Workbench doesn't run on the same machine as the web server (where phpMyAdmin is running on). In that case you have to use the IP address of the machine MySQL is running on.